# Problema en edición de registros en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems, activerecord

Buenas tardes,
Estoy intentando poner filtros en mi sitio para que me vaya mostrando datos desde la base de datos de manera ordenada según el filtro usado, para esto he creado algunos métodos en el controlador que llaman a unos scopes del modelo, Lo que necesito aquí es saber como llamar a los métodos del controlador desde la vista.

Vista:

```
<P>Ordenar por:</P>
  <p><%= link_to "Nombre", :method => 'nombre' %>
   - <%= link_to "Vistas", :method => 'vista' %>
   - <%= link_to "Precio", :method => 'precio' %>
   - <%= link_to "Fecha de Creación", :method => 'fecha' %></p>
```

Controlador:

```
def index
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).nombres
end

def nombre
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).nombres
end

def vista
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).visitas
end

def precio
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).precios
end

def fecha
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).ultimos
end
```

Modelo:

```
scope :ultimos, ->{ order("created_at DESC") }
scope :nombres, ->{ order("nombre") }
scope :visitas, ->{ order("visitas") }
scope :precios, ->{ order("precio") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que tu código es demasiado largo, podrías optimizarlo utilizando `index` únicamente junto con un `scope` que tome una variable; por ejemplo:

**Controlador**

```
def index
  @orden = Producto.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).ordena(params[:sort].presence || "nombre")
end
```

`params[:sort].presence || "nombre"` lo que hace es pasar el parámetro `sort` solo si **no** está vacío (o nulo); en caso que lo esté, entonces pasa el valor `"nombre"`.

**Modelo**

```
scope :ordena, -> (custom_sort) { order("#{custom_sort}") }
```

**Vista**

```
<p>Ordenar por:</p>
<p>
    <%= link_to "Nombre", productos_path(sort: "nombre") %>
  - <%= link_to "Vistas", productos_path(sort: "visitas") %>
  - <%= link_to "Precio", productos_path(sort: "precio") %>
  - <%= link_to "Fecha de Creación", productos_path(sort: "created_at DESC") %>
</p>
```

Donde `productos_path` se refiere al *helper* de la ruta para la acción `index` de tu controlador.

Comment: Estimado, nuevamente agradezco tu ayuda, ahora si me esta filtrando bien por cada una de las opciones.

Comment: Aprovecho de mencionar que tuve que modificar el nombre de la variable custom_sort que no me la estaba reconociendo en un principio y analizando tu código vi que tenia que ser igual al nombre que esta declarado dentro del hash orden por lo cual quedo de la siguiente manera:
scope :ordena, -> (custom_sort) { order("#{custom_sort}") }

Comment: @RaúlMarioPozoHenríquez Ah, cierto; error de dedo! Gracias por destacarlo. :)